# Windows 7 Primary Folder Icon File?

Tags: windows-7, shell, icons

In Windows XP and earlier, when changing a folder's icon, you can select system32\shell32.dll for a wide selection of built-in windows icons that include most folder types.

In Windows 7, you can still access these icons, but they don't scale up when zooming or behave like the "new" folder icons do.  In what file are these new icons stored?

I know I could download an external icon set, but I would prefer to use the built in ones if possible.

Comment: Huh? What behaviors are you referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some icons in Shell32.dll have been updated with larger (256-pixel) sizes, and some haven't.

You can also look in the new `C:\Windows\System32\Imageres.dll` file, which contains more icons.

Comment: imageres.dll is exactly what I was looking for!